# How to build push notification in mobile application using mosquitto?

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, mosquitto

I learned that PUSH NOTIFICATION service is like a persistent TCP connection.
But I don't know how maintain the connection even if the phone terminate the app.

In mobile application, if the subscription is destroyed, how we publish and deliver the message?

Should I use GCM, APNS or SMS? And wait until client subscribe the topic?

Answer (score 0):

That's correct, you have to be connected with the broker (mosquitto broker in this case) to receive the push notification (you also must be subscribed to topic).

In Android I'm using [paho](https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/android/) client libray, a [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) for keep connection in background, and *BroadcastReceiver* to start service at reboot.

For iOS you can find swift and Objetive-C MQTT-client librarys (I'm using *CocoaMQTT*) but you can't keep connection in background indefinitely. You have to use APNS.